# Why is GL_FRONT and GL_BACK deprecated in opengl 3.2 onwards

Tags: opengl, polygon

In glPolygonMode, OpenGL 3.2 onwards, I can not pass GL_FRONT or GL_BACK individually.
e.g
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
generates invalid enum: (GL_INVALID_ENUM error generated. Polygon modes for  are disabled in the current profile.)

Can somebody explain why is this deprecated? Why must I pass in both faces(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)

What if I want to "line fill" the front face, and then,  "completely fill" the back face of a polygon?

Unfortunately this link (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml) does not mention anything about this. Atleast it should have mentioned why are they deprecrated or how can you fill the faces differently.

Comment: A shader can look at the (transformed) normal vector to determine whether it is rendering the front or back face.

Comment: Draw your polygons twice, culling a different side each time. Consider yourself lucky this even exists in OpenGL 3.2 core at all - it was removed from GLES.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Can you also please answer the question on why the ARB decided to deprecate these face options?

Comment: @BenVoigt. I know how to find/specify the side of the polygon, but that is not my question here. Sorry if its not very clear.

Comment: @kvikram: It is deprecated because a shader can do it, so a special function is not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a different fill mode per-side, you can draw your polygons twice, culling a different side each time.

You should consider yourself lucky this even exists in OpenGL 3.2 core at all, because it was removed from OpenGL ES. Furthermore, in D3D you have never been able to specify a polygon fill mode per-side.

In truth, you can implement your own really advanced fill modes using a combination of geometry shaders and fragment shaders in OpenGL 3.2 (and do it per-side). Since the primitive assembly pipeline is programmable now, it makes sense to ditch some of the things that have no dedicated fixed-function hardware (granted fill mode is technically a rasterization state). Likewise, the fixed-function alpha test was removed since it can be done in fragment shaders now.

---

As for where the deprecation of `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` is discussed, you will have to read the core specification to find this.

#### [OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.withchanges.pdf) - E.2. Deprecated and Removed Features - pp. 332

> Separate polygon draw mode - PolygonMode face values of `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK`; polygons are always drawn in the same mode, no matter which face is being rasterized.

If you browse through the entire list of deprecated things in 3.2 core, you will notice quite a few things related to per-side rasterization were removed. Luckily we still have two-sided stencil, but of course this goes back to the fact that stencil test is not programmable.

Comment: ok, so what you are saying is : specifying a different fill method for both sides was more of a software implementation of the pipeline, and since hardware does not support this, this has been removed.

Comment: @kvikram: Well, not entirely... the point I was getting at is that having a per-side fill mode actually undermines the programmability of the rasterization stage (fragment shaders). It is something that happens during rasterization that is out of the control of fragment shaders. The trend has been to remove fixed-function parts of the pipeline that can be implemented in shaders.