Why did glGet with GL_POLYGON_MODE returns two values?
When getting the mode of GL_POLYGON_MODE, glGetIntergerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, data), I'll have to make data an integer array of size 2.
because I've read somewhere that:

params returns two values: symbolic constants indicating whether front-facing and back-facing polygons are rasterized as points, lines, or filled polygons. The initial value is GL_FILL. See glPolygonMode.

So one is for GL_FRONT (data[0]), the other for GL_BACK (data[1]).
But since OpenGL3.2, PolygonMode face values of GL_FRONT and GL_BACK are deprecated, polygons are always drawn in the same mode, no matter which face is being rasterized.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672297/9629055)
Meaning you can only use GL_FRONT_AND_BACK in glPolygonMode, no longer can you use glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE) nor glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE).
So my questions are:

Why did glGet still returns two values for GL_POLYGON_MODE, while you can only use GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, I'm expecting only one value since front and back are always in the same mode.
Is it safe to assume that when I write this glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, data), data[0] always equals data[1]?
also, why can't I find the description of GL_POLYGON_MODE in OpenGL4 reference pages as of now(2024 April 29), is it still under construction?


deprecated is not removed. When it is deprecated it still has to be present because its still used by some


It doesn't. GL_POLYGON_MODE is no longer supported for queries starting from OpenGL 3.1. 2) There is no version where (according to the standard) front and back must be the same and you can query the state. Thus not applicable. 3) Because it's not supported in any version covered by the OpenGL4 reference page.


@463035818_is_not_an_ai but when I tried to call glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE) on OpenGL 3.3, it gives me GL_INVALID_ENUM.

@BDL 1) But how am I going to know which polygon mode OpenGL is using now?
2) I believe it's in OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile - E.2. Deprecated and Removed Features - pp. 332
3) But In GL4 reference page here, I suggested you can query that with glGet

thats because I (and perhaps you too) misread the answer you linked at first. I does not say that they are deprecated, but it says it is "deprecated and removed". My comment isnt wrong. "deprecated" means you shouldnt use it. "removed" means you cannot

Since you're the one who sets the polygon mode in first place, you should be able to store which mode you set last. In general, you should try to avoid calling glGet commands during a frame anyway because it will force the GPU to flush the command buffer which can cause significant performance issues.

@BDL Hmmm... If calling glGet causes performance issues, then maybe I'll store the information somewhere instead. I was trying to let a model always draw in GL_FILL, without disturbing other models' polygon mode. That's why I need glGet to get the before mode, so to "reset" after.

@WeberLin: With states like polygon mode (which are rarely touched), it's usually better to pick a presumed default (like GL_FILL). All rendering code assumes that it was given the default value, so if some code wants to use something else, it must change it and change it back to fill. That way, you don't have to query anything (either from OpenGL or with your own state).

GL_FRONT_AND_BACK is still setting two values: the front value and the back value. The inability to set these to different values doesn't change the fact that there are functionally two separate values.
Now, the main reason they're two separate values is compatibility with compatibility profiles. Core profile code (where front and back are always the same) ought to be able to work in compatibility contexts (where front and back can be different). So if glGetIntegerv returned 2 values in compatibility, but only one in core, core-based code running in a compatibility context could cause a buffer overrun because they would only be sending a single integer to something that's going to fill in an array of 2.
That's bad.

But since OpenGL3.2, PolygonMode face values of GL_FRONT and GL_BACK are deprecated

Just FYI: they are removed; it is an error to use those enums. "Deprecated" and "removed" aren't the same thing.

Are you sure that it is possible to query GL_POLYGON_MODE in core profile?

@BDL: POLYGON_MODE is specified in the state table for core. It says glGetIntegerv right there.

So if I, for some reason, needs to query GL_POLYGON_MODE with glGetIntegerv, I should better use an integer array of size 2, just in case it returns 2 values?

@WeberLin: It's not "just in case"; it always returns two values. The behavior of the function is the same in core and compatibility.

But on my machine, it only fills one value https://imgur.com/4xaWmq3. Maybe it does fill 2 value but just so happen the second one is gibberish?
Here are some information about my computer, hope its sufficient:
OpenGL Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation \n
OpenGL Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2 \n
OpenGL Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 536.23 \n
OpenGL Shading Language Version: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
